# Convert date/time string into numeric value

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to convert this date:

`April 01, 2015 at 02:11PM`

into Excel date format. I tried Format Cell and then I looked through several dates, but no format fitted.

Any recommendation how to convert it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)&"-"&MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,4)&" "&MID(A1,FIND("at ",A1)+3,5)&" "&RIGHT(A1,2))
```

with formatting to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you use the formula =now() you only get the date but you actually want the time

=TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

- If you have today´s date on Cell A1

=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")